# how to disable xml element attribute sorting

Tags: xml, dom, element, attr, domparser

I want to know how to disable the attribute sorting in xml element. I have a document like this:

```
        Document document = builder.newDocument();
        Element rootElement = document.createElement("ROOT");
        document.appendChild(rootElement);

        // set attribute to root element
        Attr attr = document.createAttribute("ID");
        attr.setValue("1");
        rootElement.setAttributeNode(attr);
        Attr attr = document.createAttribute("CODE");
        attr.setValue("A");
        rootElement.setAttributeNode(attr);
```

After execute the program I got result like this:

```
        <ROOT CODE="A" ID="1"></ROOT>
```

My question is even i put id as a first attribute the code attribute is coming first. I need id to come first for my server requirement. I'm using java to create this.

Answer (score 0):

The order of attributes is officially not significant in XML, and tools are not required to maintain it. (In fact there are often good performance reasons not to do so). You really do need to rewrite your code so it doesn't require that the attributes arrive in any particular order.

Comment: well, technically the server is out from my control and cannot fix anything in there.  :( thanks for the answer

Comment: If the server is sensitive to attribute order, and claims to be processing XML, it is broken. Send a bug report, or discard it in favor of one written correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't get the recipient software fixed, recent releases of Saxon have an option on the serializer to control the order of attributes in the output.

```
<xsl:output saxon:attribute-order="ID CODE"/>
```

(However, if they're failing to accept attributes in any order, this probably means they are trying to process the XML without using a conformant XML parser, e.g by regex hacking, and so this probably won't be the end of your troubles).